# "Train of thought" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, modismos

¿Está bien traducir **Train of thought** como *Corriente de pensamiento*?

Veo que mucha gente usa *Tren de pensamiento* o *Línea de pensamiento* pero siento que la primera es incorrecta porque *tren* normalmente se usa con un sentido de secuencia o repetición (*En tren de bromas*) y que en la segunda *línea* respeta la idea de continuidad pero debilita la intención que, me parece, **train** le confiere a la frase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como español, he relacionado *Tren de pensamiento* como un tren imaginario antes que relacionarlo con "corriente".

Así que considero *Corriente de pensamiento* o *Línea de pensamiento* mucho más aceptables que Tren de pensamiento, que creo que es desaconsejable, al menos en España.

Comment: Gracias Replica. Todavía no puedo votar respuestas, espero poder hacerlo pronto.

Answer (score 3):

Para añadir a las respuestas anteriores: **ilación** es una palabra que se corresponde bastante bien con el uso habitual de la expresión *"train of thought"*, cuando se refiere no tanto al pensamiento en sí sino a su expresión  articulada - el discurso. Según el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KxRP8xT): *"Trabazón razonable y ordenada de las partes de un discurso."*

Un detalle que añade confusión: la expresión "*perder el **hilo** (del argumento, discurso, razonamiento)*" también sería una traducción aceptable de *"to loose the train of thought"*. Sin embargo, este "*hilo*" no tiene nada que ver con la palabra "*ilación*". Detalles [aquí](http://hurgapalabras.blogspot.com.ar/2009/04/ilacion.html).

Comment: Muy interesante. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

*Corriente de pensamiento* is right, normal and habitual. I've heard it many times. The concept is very similar to that used in a technique called "stream of consciousness" (*corriente de la conciencia*).

In any case, "*corriente*" have the same sense of "*tren*" as *sequence*, and therefore there is not any problem with translating it as *tren de pensamiento*, recognizing that in both cases is a metaphor. And I can also add, with the same meaning:

> *hilo* de ideas
>
> *cadena* de pensamientos

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. I cannot vote you up yet because I'm new here and don't have the reputation required (15 points)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corriente+de+pensamiento%2Bcorrientes+de+pensamiento%2Cl%C3%ADnea+de+pensamiento%2Bl%C3%ADneas+de+pensamiento%2Ccadena+de+pensamientos%2Bcadenas+de+pensamientos&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28corriente%20de%20pensamiento%20%2B%20corrientes%20de%20pensamiento%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28l%C3%ADnea%20de%20pensamiento%20%2B%20l%C3%ADneas%20de%20pensamiento%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28cadena%20de%20pensamientos%20%2B%20cadenas%20de%20pensamientos%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Rodrigo no obstante lo de NGrams, a mí me parece un poco diferente *corriente de pensamiento* y *línea de pensamiento*.  ¿Para ti son sinónimos e intercambiables?

Comment: @guifa tal vez _línea_ corresponde más a una secuencia lógica en la que las ideas se siguen una después de la otra (p.ej. una argumentación, una deducción, una narración...). Mientras que _corriente_ da la idea de "flujo acelerado", entonces se puede usar para pensamientos desordenados, o con alguna lógica no lineal... La verdad no lo sé, estoy especulando, pero me queda claro que tienes razón y no son exactamente intercambiables.

Comment: A mi corriente de pensamiento me suena más a una moda o conjunto de personas que piensan de la misma manera por influencia de algo, lo que es la *corriente* en ese momento. La línea de pensamiento de una corriente de pensamiento sería la descripción de esas ideas.